# CLLocationCoordinate2D change the value to nil

Tags: ios, cllocationcoordinate2d

I have this function which shows me coordinates of the pin on the map

```
-(void)newLocationSeleced:(CLLocation *) newLocation
{
_selectedLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);

NSLog(@"newLatitude: %f, newLongitude: %f", _selectedLocation.latitude, _selectedLocation.longitude);
```

}

After calling this function I can see that new latitude has correct values as well as new longitude

> newLatitude: 42.448826, newLongitude: 19.250086

But if I try to call new function (I call this function after clicking on the button) which contents just this line of code:

```
 NSLog(@"new latitude: %f, new longitude: %f", _selectedLocation.latitude, _selectedLocation.longitude);
```

I can see this msg:

> new latitude: 0.000000, new longitude: 0.000000

It should show me same values as in the first message which is showing after calling first function.

And in the .h I have this

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite)CLLocationCoordinate2D selectedLocation;
```

Comment: may be _selectedLocation set somewhere else

Comment: I'm pretty much sure that I mention everything that is important.

Comment: change _selectedLocation to self.selectedLocation and try

Comment: I already tried that. Same thing.

Comment: ok. cant judge the issue from given code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39886/discussion-between-subasa-and-ketan-patel)